# Cannot Connect To MySQL / Other Error. Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Trying to access a MySQL database on my machine. It's on port 1338.

This is the PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>


<body>

    <table>
    <?php

        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost:1338","root","password"); //connects to db
        $selected = mysql_select_db("site_updatelog"); //selects the db to be used
        //Check whether connection was successful
        if(!$connection){
            die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error()); //Stop further execution of php script and show the error that occured
        }

        $sql = "SELECT comments, version, datetime FROM changeLog ORDER BY id DESC"; //form the query to be executed on the db
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $connections) or die (mysql_error()); //execute the query, or die if there was an error

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            //Display the table of results
            echo "<tr><td>". $row['version'] ."</td><td>". $row['comments'] ."</td><td>". $row['datetime'] ."</td></tr>";
        }

        mysql_close($connection);
     ?>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

This is the output:

```
"; } mysql_close($connection); ?>
". $row['version'] ."   ". $row['comments'] ."  ". $row['datetime'] ."
```

Been messing around for quite a while and it still wont work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use mysql_* it is depricated . Use PDO

Comment: Tried both of these and the output was still the same.

I am using that MySQL 5.5 utility for this as well.

Answer (score 1):

change `mysql_query($sql, $connections)` with `mysql_query($sql, $connection)`

Comment: are you sure this is the exact example you have in your script? please give me all the code you have

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is because you have unescaped characters in your data which you are echoing - try to wrap your $row['comments'], $row['version'] and $row['datetime'] to [htmlspecialschars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below only dies and reports error if `(!$connection)`

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost:1338","root","password"); //connects to db
        $selected = mysql_select_db("site_updatelog"); //selects the db to be used
        //Check whether connection was successful
        if(!$connection){
            die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error()); //Stop further execution of php script and show the error that occured
        }
```

Try using

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost:1338","root","password"); //connects to db
        //Check whether connection was successful
        if(!$connection){
            die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error()); //Stop further execution of php script and show the error that occured
        }
        $selected = mysql_select_db("site_updatelog",$connection); //selects the db to be used
        if (!$db_selected) {
            die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
        }
        $sql = "SELECT comments, version, datetime FROM changeLog ORDER BY id DESC"; //form the query to be executed on the db
        $result = mysql_query($sql) ;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            //Display the table of results
            echo "<tr><td>". $row['version'] ."</td><td>". $row['comments'] ."</td><td>". $row['datetime'] ."</td></tr>";
        }

        mysql_close($connection);
```

This throws errors before running query. Also changed `mysql_fetch_array()` to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` as `mysql_fetch_array()` requires 2 parameters